# Adding together two arrays and print into third array

Tags: c++, arrays

Before I start I must notice that I am a begginer in C++.
I have a code (see below), In this code I have two arrays with 10 random numbers but In tab_A numbers are the same like in tab_B - I don't know how to solve this. Also I don't know how to merge/add/sum these two arrays in new array tab_C and print result.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int gen() {
  return rand() % 11;
}
int main()
{
    
    int tab_A[10];
    cout<<"TABLICA A DEBUG"<<endl;
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        tab_A[i] = gen();
        cout<<tab_A[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    int tab_B[10];
    cout<<"TABLICA B DEBUG"<<endl;
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        tab_B[i] = gen();
        cout<<tab_B[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    int tab_C[10];
    cout<<"TABLICA C DEBUG"<<endl;
    
    int sumAB=0;
    sumAB=tab_A[10]+tab_B[10];
    
    tab_C[10]=sumAB;
    cout<<tab_C[10]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example as to how you want to add the two arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code, you have called `srand` twice with the same seed. Hence, the numbers that will be randomly generated will be the [same](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/). If you want to generate random numbers it is advisable to set seed only once.

Also, there seems to be an issue in the code. C++ has 0-indexing. Hence, the lines

```
sumAB=tab_A[10]+tab_B[10];
tab_C[10]=sumAB;
cout<<tab_C[10]<<endl;
```

will give errors.

As the size of `tab_C` is 10 so the index of the last element would be 9.

Comment: Okay srand solvet. Now I have problem with tab_C. As output I have "1". I changed that array size to 11

Comment: Do you want to add element by element?

Comment: I want to perform the addition
```int sumAB=0;
    sumAB=tab_A[10]+tab_B[10];
    
    for(int i=0; i<tab_C[10]; i++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<tab_C[10]; i++)
        {
            tab_C[i]=sumAB;
        }
    }
    ```
this is my last code